# Updating a Pod with its Secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have a kubernetes deployment which uses secrets for environment variables. So the pod has env variables which are using the secret.

Now I updated my deployment manifest json and the secret json to remove some of the variables, but when I apply these files, I get **CreateContainerConfigError** for the pod, and in its description I see:

> Couldn't find key FOO in Secret mynamespace/secret-mypod

I've deleted this key from my secret json and from the deployment manifest json. Why am I still getting this error?

I understand that I can delete the deployment and apply it to get it to work, but I don't want to do that.

What is the right way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a `replace` on the deployment json. If the original deployment had the usual update settings, a new pod will be created with the new deployment config. If it starts ok, the old one will be deleted.

To be safer, you could create a new secret with some version indicator in the name, refer to the new secret name in the new deployment definition. That way if there's a problem with the new pod or the old needs to be redeployed, the old secret will still be there.

Comment: I see, makes sense. I tried it out, but I still get the same error. Why does it not automatically pick it up though? Since I deleted the key from both the deployment and the secret, I was expecting it to now have this issue. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure, and sort of guessing... but maybe the deployment was changed before the secret?

Comment: I see. Btw, I tried replace but it failed with the same error.

Comment: @Ufder, does `kubectl apply --force` or `kubectl replace --force` work? Both delete and re-create resources and may bypass graceful
deletion though.

Comment: @VikramHosakote would like to avoid the force if possible!